# How to work with quantiz in matlab/octave?

Tags: matlab, math, octave

I have a code which resizes an image and gets its entropy.
Resize works correctly, but I cannot do something with quantiz.
This function throws

```
Error using quantiz (line 31)
The input signal must be a real vector.
```

Error. How to fix it?(GrayImage is 2D array with values from 0 to 255)

```
normalImage = imread("porshe.bmp");
grayImage = rgb2gray(normalImage);
width = 750;
heigth = 500;
ebase = entropy(grayImage);
resizedImage2 = imresize(grayImage,0.5);
resizedImage4 = imresize(grayImage,0.25);
er2 = entropy(resizedImage2);
er4 = entropy(resizedImage4);
quantizImage8 = quantiz(grayImage,8);
quantizImage16 = quantiz(grayImage,16);
quantizImage64 = quantiz(grayImage,64);
imshow(quantizImage64)
```

Comment: I have never used `quantiz`, but both the error you get and the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/quantiz.html#d122e66479) say that the input has to be a _vector_. You may need to reshape the input to a vector, then reshape back to the original shape, using [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)

Comment: I can confirm that the above code works fine in octave both as it is, and when treated as a vector and subsequently reshaped. (tested using an arbitrary porsche logo off the internet)